# Asynchronous Where Filter with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

I have a `List` of elements which is populated through an `async` call of a WebService (no problem there).

I need to filter that list in order to show something on the application view. I tried this:

```
List<DateTime> dates = EventsDates.Where(x => x.Day == tmp.Day && x.Month == tmp.Month && x.Year == tmp.Year).ToList();
```

I also tried using the `Select` function of LINQ. The problem is that any time this code is called, the `EventsDates` list isn't populated, the WebService hasn't responded yet.

How could I try to filter the `EventsDates` list asynchronously?

Comment: Try materializing the query with `ToList()` or `ToArray()` before filtering the data with your `Where` clause.

Comment: Can you show how do you obtain `EventsDates`?

Comment: Can you give us a little more of the code? Why are you storing Day, Month and Year as separate fields? How is `tmp` populated? It looks like it's the same data type (`EventDates`?), so does `EventDates` implement `IEquatable<T>`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Where" shouldn't be async, you need to do EventsDates fill awaitable. Something like this:

```
EventsDates = await YourWebServiceMethodCall();
List<DateTime> dates = EventsDates.Where (x => x.Day == tmp.Day && x.Month == tmp.Month && x.Year == tmp.Year).ToList();
```

Comment: EventsDates was populated inside the CallWebService function. I updated this and instead return a list that populated EventsDates with using await. EventsDates is then filter in another function but still no data in the list when the code is called.

Comment: @MartinStievenart When you debug are you getting values on this line: EventsDates = await YourWebServiceMethodCall(); The issue is most likely in the service not the where filter. Can you update you question with the relevant parts of the service that returns the data?

Comment: Just after the line EventsDates = await YourWebServiceMethodCall(); i have elements in the list yes. Do you think it's still linked to the service ? I could update my question but it's quite long so i'll need a few time to do it.

Comment: Ok i think i resolve the issue. The function that use EventsDates list was not an async function. I put it in the same function that await the CallWebService and it's working now :) Thanks everyone

Answer (score 12):

You can call it asynchronously like this but as others have stated you need to await the eventDates to unwrap the response from the service before you use it. @Dmitry's answer is correct. I just put this here to answer your question of how to use Where asynchronously in case you need it in the future.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

List<DateTime> dates = await EventsDates.Where(x => x.Day == tmp.Day && x.Month == tmp.Month && x.Year == tmp.Year).ToListAsync();
```

You can also do this:

```
var list = someCollection.Where(async x => x.Prop == await SomeLongRunningProcess());
```

Comment: System.Data.Entity is the Entity Framework right ? I don't think i'll add the package just to filter a list. But thanks for the info

Comment: `ToListAsync()` requires that the underlying data source implement `IDbAsyncEnumerable` which is an EF interface. If you try to use it on a non EF collection it will throw an exception. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn313107

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you aren't `await`ing the result to populate `EventDates`.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this Microsoft documentation, what you should do is just wait for the asynchronous list to return after the query
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking?redirectedfrom=MSDN#testing-with-async-queries

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
var consult =  EventsDates.Where(x => x.Day == tmp.Day && x.Month == tmp.Month && x.Year == tmp.Year)

List<DateTime> dates = await consult.ToListAsync();
```